# Error exporting PDF with FOP "fo:list-item" is not a valid child of "fo:list-item-body"!

Tags: java, xml, apache, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We're getting an error when trying to export a PDF with fop:

SEVERE: Exception
org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:list-item" is not a valid child of "fo:list-item-body"! (No context info available)
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:list-item" is not a valid child of "fo:list-item-body"! (No context info available)

From what I can tell our XSL looks like it should run. Here's an excerpt from the XSL.

```html
 <xsl:template match="ol" mode="section-body">
    <fo:list-block keep-together="always">
    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="section-body" />
        </fo:list-item-body> 
    </fo:list-item>      
    </fo:list-block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul" mode="section-body">
    <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="40mm" content-width="2.5in">
    <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="section-body"/>
            </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item> 
    </fo:list-block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li" mode="section-body">
    <xsl:element name="fo:list-item">
      
      <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:list-item-label>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="parent::ol">
            <xsl:element name="fo:block" use-attribute-sets="list-marker-number"><xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),'.')" /></xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="fo:block" use-attribute-sets="list-marker">•</xsl:element>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </fo:list-item-label>
      <fo:list-item-body>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="parent::ol">
            <xsl:element name="fo:block" use-attribute-sets="list-item-number">
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="section-body"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="fo:block">
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="section-body"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </fo:list-item-body>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your templates for `ol` and `ul` both generate:

```
<fo:list-block keep-together="always">
<fo:list-item>
    <fo:list-item-label>
    </fo:list-item-label>
    <fo:list-item-body>
    <-- Result of processing <li> goes here! -->
    </fo:list-item-body> 
</fo:list-item>      
</fo:list-block>
```

and each `li` generates an `fo:list-item` that contains an `fo:list-item-label` and an `fo:list-item-body`.

If you remove the `fo:list-item`, `fo:list-item-label`, and `fo:list-item-body` from your `ol` and `ul` templates:

```
<xsl:template match="ol" mode="section-body">
  <fo:list-block keep-together="always">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="section-body" />
  </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul" mode="section-body">
  <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="40mm" content-width="2.5in">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="section-body"/>
  </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>
```

then you won't be generating an `fo:list-item` inside an `fo:list-item-body`.

If you want to try validating your FO outside of FOP, then I suggest **focheck** at https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck

Comment: Can you suggest me how to iterate an ArrayList of objects while generating a pdf using Apache fop and a POJO.

Comment: I suggest that you start a new question about that and see if anyone can answer it for you.

Comment: Yeah. I have a question here, if you might want to have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675189/how-to-iterate-over-a-list-while-generating-pdf-using-apache-fop